# Return a True/False Boolean from an InStr function? vba

Tags: excel, vba

I'd like to make a loop with an if function in it. The condition for this if funtion needs to be the active cell containing a "*"or not.

-The If - like funtion does not work because the like function does not recognize "*" figures because it uses these to define parts of strings.

- I think combining a regular if funtion with an InStr function could work, but I'm not sure how to combine these.

**How do I return a True/False Boolean from an InStr function?**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
Do While ActiveCell.Value <>"" 
    If InStr(ActiveCell.Value, "*") Then
        MsgBox("Cell contains at least one '*'")
    Else
    End if
    ActiveCell.Offset(1,0)
Loop
```

Comment: fwiw, I usually add a CBool wrapper (e.g. `If CBool(InStr(ActiveCell.Value, "*")) Then`) just to remind myself that the [InStr function](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8460tsh1%28v=vs.90%29.aspx)  is being used as a boolean.

Comment: Why the hanging `Else:`?

Comment: Fair point, no reason at all for the hanging "Else:", just my lack of experience with this language i think. I just edited it. Thanks! :D

Answer (score 0):

```
Do While ActiveCell.Value <> "" 
    If InStr(ActiveCell.Value, "*") <> 0 Then
        MsgBox("Cell contains at least one '*'")
    Else
        MsgBox("Cell does not contain at least one '*'")
    End if
    ActiveCell.Offset(1,0)
Loop
```

The String Expression either contains a location for the special character or not. If not, then the Instr returned value will be 0.