# Excel VBA - Get top cell from column where top cell is merged

Tags: vba, excel

I have a macro where I am going through columns and identifying whether the "top" cell (row 7, because there are various irrelevant headers) matches certain specified values, and then performing various actions.

The problem is that some of the headers are merged cells.  This means that the code correctly recognises only columns which align with the left-most column which the header cell straddles.  Clearly, I need to change this to resolve this.

I don't know how to get this to record a value for, e.g., column D and Column E, where a merged cell in both column D and E says "manager" or "director".

For the moment, I've just included a made-up action ("y = 22") because I'm trying to get the basic principle right before progressing.

```
Sub LabourCalc()

    Dim x As Variant
    Dim y As Variant

    Workbooks("XXX").Activate
    Sheets("XXX").Activate

    For x = 1 To 10
        If InStr(Cells(7, x).Value, "MANAGER") _
        Or InStr(Cells(7, x).Value, "manager") _
        Or InStr(Cells(7, x).Value, "Manager") _
        Or InStr(Cells(7, x).Value, "DIRECTOR") _
        Or InStr(Cells(7, x).Value, "Director") _
        Or InStr(Cells(7, x).Value, "director") Then
            y = 22
        End If
    Next x

End Sub
```

Comment: It's not clear what your expected result is. Also, `InStr()` returns an integer, not a boolean, so this code is not valid. Another thing to clean up is that all of the case matching can be simplified by converting the value from the cell to `UCase()`. This will get you started on a little bit better path: `If InStr(UCase(Cells(7, x).Value), "MANAGER") > 0 Or InStr(UCase(Cells(7, x).Value), "DIRECTOR") > 0 Then`. But you still need to provide more information about what the outcome of this should be since "y = 22" is just a placeholder.

Comment: replace `merged` cells by `center across selection`

Comment: @ValonMiller `Instr` can be used as a boolean - the `> 0` can be dropped. If desired you can add a `Cbool` wrapper as mentioned in the comments in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33627666/return-a-true-false-boolean-from-an-instr-function-vba?rq=1)

Comment: Maybe this will point you in the right direction - [detect-merged-cells-in-vba-excel-with-mergearea](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22075988/detect-merged-cells-in-vba-excel-with-mergearea)

Comment: As a follow up, `Cells(7, x).MergeArea.Cells(1, 1)` refers to the leftmost, uppermost cell of a merged cell, and is equivalent to `Cells(7, x)` if the cell is *not* merged.

Comment: @BigBen Fair enough, I would still simplify it to `If InStr(UCase(Cells(7, x).Value), "MANAGER") Or InStr(UCase(Cells(7, x).Value), "DIRECTOR") Then`

Comment: @BigBen I've been sticking to `> 0` ever since [this conversation]( https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50704939/deleting-rows-in-excel-based-on-characters/50705535#comment88424248_50705535) and because I prefer it to using `cbool`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the [`Range.MergeArea`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.range.mergearea) property.

> Returns a Range object that represents the merged range containing the specified cell. If the specified cell isn't in a merged range, this property returns the specified cell.

So for example, if `D7:E7` is a merged cell:

- `Cells(7, 4).MergeArea.Cells(1, 1)` refers to `D7`
- `Cells(7, 5).MergeArea.Cells(1, 1)` *also* refers to `D7`. Cell `E7` is empty.

And if `F7` is *not* a merged cell:

- `Cells(7, 6).MergeArea.Cells(1, 1)` refers to `F7`.

As pointed out by @ValonMiller in the comments, you can simplify the multiple `InStr` instances by first converting the contents of `Cells(7, x)` to uppercase using `UCase`.

Your final loop then could look like:

```
With Workbooks("XXX").Sheets("XXX")
    For x = 1 To 10
        With .Cells(7, x).MergeArea.Cells(1, 1)
            If InStr(UCase(.Value), "MANAGER") > 0 Or InStr(UCase(.Value), "DIRECTOR") > 0 Then
                ' Do your stuff here
            End If
        End With
    Next x
End With
```

Answer (score 1):

All those comments and no one provided an actual working answer. Try this:

```
Sub LabourCalc()

    Dim wb as Workbook
    Set wb = Workbooks("XXX")

    Dim ws as Worksheet
    Set ws = wb.Worksheets("XXX")

    For x = 1 To 10
        Select Case UCase$(ws.Cells(7,x).MergeArea.Cells(1,1))
            Case is = "MANAGER","DIRECTOR"
                'do stuff here
        End Select
    Next

End Sub
```

If you need to check if the Manager or Director appear within the cell do this:

```
Dim checkValue as String
checkValue = UCase$(ws.Cells(7,x).MergeArea.Cells(1,1))

Select Case Instr(checkValue,"MANAGER") > 0 Or Instr(checkValue,"DIRECTOR") > 0
    Case is = True
        'do stuff
End Select
```